# How does octave create a sparse submatrix

Tags: python, fortran, octave, sparse-matrix

One of the wonderful features of Octave is how it treats sparse matrices. I have been given the task of copying some Octave code into fortran (speed is critical) and specifically, given a sparse matrix Sparse(nodes,nodes), I need to come up with the submatrix SubSparse(afew,afew):

```
r=4;c=6;k=5;nz=r*k;
Sparse=spalloc(r,c,nz);
Sparse(1,1)=1;Sparse(1,2)=2;Sparse(3,5)=4;Sparse(4,6)=6;
SubSparse=Sparse([1,4],[1,6])
```

The full matrices are:

```
Sparse
1.000 2.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 4.000 0.000
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 6.000

SubSparse
1.000 0.000
0.000 6.000
```

I have [read](http://www.sce.carleton.ca/faculty/adler/talks/2006/bateman-adler-octave2006.pdf) , and [this](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/4abcc0969ebd/liboctave/array/dSparse.cc)

One thing i cannot do is recreate the full matrices, as they are way too big to fit in the machine.

In my fortran implementation for sparse matrices, I use the Hartwell-Boeing storage, dictated by my use of SuperLU to solve linear systems.  I believe octave's compressed column format is very similar.

My question is where can I find (a) the logic behind what happens when line 4 of the MWE is executed and (b) the code

Comment: This isn't really a code problem, it's a linear algebra problem.

Comment: @Ross I disagree, there is no linear algebra involved here.  This is purely a question of efficient storage and search.  Someone in the octave world has figured out how to do this.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: What kinds of operations do you intend to perform on these matrices?

Comment: @Ross as explained in the OP, the matrices are coefficient matrices in linear systems of equations.  The linear algebra problem of finding the solution is done with SuperLU, which requires the matrix to be in a specific format: Hartwell-Boeing.  Storing a matrix in HB format is straightforward.  The problem comes when one needs to generate a submatrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indexing a sparse matrix so you need to look into the [Sparse class](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/3b211e9ceab1/liboctave/array/Sparse.h) which is part of liboctave which is in C++.  The method you seem to be looking for is [`Sparse<T> Sparse<T>::index (const idx_vector& idx_i, const idx_vector& idx_j, bool resize_ok)`](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/3b211e9ceab1/liboctave/array/Sparse.cc#l1578).

If you plan on using that implementation on another program, note the license of the code which is GPLv3+.